# Convert List of custom object into CharSequence

Tags: java, android

I have a list of custom object named `customObjectList`. I want it to bind into `AlertDialog.Builder.setMultiChoiceItems()`, which need to convert it into CharSequence first, 

This is how I do it: `customObjectList.toArray(new CharSequence[customObjectList.size()])` but I got this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.idea.customobject cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.CharSequence[]
```

what is the correct way to convert?

Comment: Hey man, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you're trying to create a `CharSequence` of something that does not implement the `CharSequence` interface (your `CustomObject` class). You could use the `toArray` method if the two types were the same, which they're not. So the alternative that I propose is simply doing it manually. I suppose that your `customObject` class has some kind of a String value that you wanna display in the options, so just use that then and do a for loop, like so:

```
CharSequence[] myArray = new CharSequence[customObjectList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < customObjectList.size(); i++){
    myArray[i] = customObjectList.get(i).getTitle(); // Whichever string you wanna store here from custom object
}
```

Now you can simply use `myArray` for `setMultiChoiceItems`. Hope you understand the idea and I got your problem as well.